# Extract Data from a Dynamically Changing Pivot Table Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table set up in this fashion:

:[image]

I want to group all Nodes and put each version under each group of Nodes:

[image]

The Versions are not constant but it is a sorted list and new Nodes could show up in this list or disappear from the pivot table.
My current thinking is to use a loop to extract the values and compare previous node to current node. But how would I know what the first item to compare would be? If there is a better method, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Closing page... I realize I could just set the very first item in a variable.